# Plot two legends in same map with GeoPandas

Tags: python, shapefile, labeling, geopandas, legend

I'm trying to plot two shape files: shape_geo and shape_dam, but the legend for the second map doesn't show up.
This is the code I'm trying:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
shape_geo.plot(ax=ax, column='Litologia', legend=True, legend_kwds={"loc": 'center left'},alpha=0.5)
shape_dam.plot(ax=ax,alpha=0.5,color='green',legend=True, legend_kwds={'label': 'Dam'})
leg = ax.get_legend()
leg.set_bbox_to_anchor((1.04, 0.5))
```

And this is the image reproduced:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

After some research, this is what I manage to do:

```
import matplotlib.patches as patches
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax1 = clip_geo.plot(ax = ax, linewidth=1, edgecolor="black",column='Litologia', cmap=cmap, legend=True, legend_kwds={"loc": 'center left'},alpha=0.8)
ax2 = points_gdf.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=1, color="blue", markersize=8,label='Outros CPT')
ax3 = pnt_filito.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=1, color="yellow", markersize=8,label='CPT no Filito ')

legend1 = ax.legend(scatterpoints=1, frameon=True,
        labelspacing=1, loc='lower left', fontsize=8, 
        bbox_to_anchor=(0.03,0.05),
        title="CPT", 
        title_fontsize=10)
fig.gca().add_artist(legend1)
    
list_of_lito = ['Areia', 'Dolomito','Filito',
                'Saprolito']

color_dict = {'Areia':'red',
            'Dolomito':'darkcyan',
            'Filito':'magenta',
            'Saprolito':'green'}

# Creates a rectangular patch for each contaminant, using the colors above
patch_list =[]
for lito in list_of_lito:
    label = lito.capitalize()
    color = color_dict[lito]
    patch_list.append(patches.Patch(facecolor=color, 
                                    label=label, 
                                    alpha=0.9, 
                                    linewidth=2, 
                                    edgecolor='black'))

# Creates a legend with the list of patches above.
ax.legend(handles=patch_list, fontsize=8, loc='lower left',
        bbox_to_anchor = (.8,0.75),title='Litologia', title_fontsize=10)
# show figure
plt.rcParams['legend.title_fontsize'] = 10

plt.show()
```

Which results in this image:

[image]